# Git not showing remote branch in sub folder

Tags: git

I have a project which is placed under git. The problem is that if I go into one of the sub folders called 'www' and type `git remote` it does not show any thing but when I come to one level higher in the project then it shows the remotes.

Also this folder called 'www' , when I change something in it and then commit and try to push the changes to my remote, it does not push anything and says everything is up to date.

Any help, appreciated

Comment: @kan - nope - although i would like it to be. I did not do anything to make it a sub module. Right now I would just like it to be as is.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice investigation, but why don't you just `git submodule` in the root of you repo and assure that `www` is a submodule like @kan said.

Take a [little brief](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) what submodules are.

---

On the other hand it could be another git repo pulled in `www` directory (there should be `.git` dir in `www`).

Comment: but i never made it a sub-module. I didn't do anything!

Comment: ok I typed what you said, it says : No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path { my affected directory! }